# When using GAM in R, why is the plot for two continuos variables different from the first one plotted with two continuos by categorical?

Tags: r, statistics, gam

I'm using GAM in R and I can't understand why the output for two different equations that should give the same plot are not exactly the same.

For example, when using the mpg dataset with a multivariate equation as follows, I get the plot for the additive affect of weight and rpm in hw.mpg. Then, I want to see what happens when I plot the data of rmp by fuel type. This gives me 3 plots, and I expected the first one (weight) to be exactly the same as the one plotted previously without the "by fuel" differentiation. Am I missing something? Then what is the graph 1 in figure 2 showing?

[image: Figure 1]

To get figure 1:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
data(mpg)
mod_hwy1 <- gam(hw.mpg ~ s(weight) + s(rpm), data = mpg, method = "REML")
plot(mod_hwy1)
```

[image: Figure 2]

To get figure 2:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
mod_hwy2 <- gam(hw.mpg ~ s(weight) + s(rpm, by=fuel), data = mpg, method = "REML")
plot(mod_hwy2)
```

Using my own data is even more visible that the two graphs are not exactly the same:
[image]

Please someone help me understand!

Comment: When you add terms to a model, it changes the estimates of other terms. This is generally true, not just for GAMs.

Comment: I also think the graphs aren't as different as you think. Note the y scale in your first weight graph goes from about -20 to 20, and the smooth term covers the full range. In the second set of graphs the y scale for weight goes from about -125 to 20, but the smooth term still covers the range from about -20 to 20. The curve has similar shape, just compressed when the scale covers a wider range. This is similar in your own data.

Comment: And in case it's not clear, when you change your model from `s(rpm)` to `s(rpm, by = fuel)`, you're not just changing what plots are created. You're switching from a single smoother for `rpm` to 3 `rpm` smoothers, one for each level of `fuel`. It's a more complex model with more terms. 3 `rpm` smoothers are able to explain more of the variation than a single smoother, and some of that they are able to do better than the `s(weight)` term, which adapts accordingly.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks! I understand of course that adding terms changes graphs...but what is the meaning of the first graph when I do it by location, if it doesn't show a specific location? I assume that's showing the baseline, meaning, all locations...so that's why I expected it to be exactly the same as the one for all locations. If you see my own data carefully, you will notice a few residuals on different places. If you look at RPM that is the one affected by the "by fuel" it's clear that they should change, but why the one for weight that doesn't have the term "by fuel" added also changes?

Comment: @GregorThomas You mean that the second figure (first graph) is still using the smoother for fuel, even for the weight variable?

Comment: Yes, `mod_hwy2` is a single model with multiple terms.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your model is that you forgot to include the group means for the levels of `fuel`. As a result, the smooths, which are centred about the overall mean of the response are having to also model the group means for the levels of fuel.

Fit the model as:

```r
mod_hwy2 <- gam(hw.mpg ~ fuel + # <--- group means
                  s(weight) + s(rpm, by=fuel),
                data = mpg, method = "REML")
```

Then add in Gregor's point about these effects being conditional upon the other terms in the model and you should be able to understand what's going one and why things change.

And regarding one of your comments; the locations are shown in your plot, look at the label for the y-axis of each plot.